# PHP Heredoc with Arrays and Writing Bash Scripts

Tags: php, arrays, bash, heredoc

I'm trying to write a bash script from within PHP. I have an array of functions to run that I want to append to the script, along with custom code snippets and other variables.

```
$my_array_of_bash_cmds =
Array (
    [0] => bash_cmd1
    [1] => bash_cmd2
    [2] => bash_cmd3
)
```

Using a simple heredoc such as:

```
$bash_script = <<<EOD
#!/bin/bash
cd {$path}
echo "You are in `pwd`."
{$my_array_of_bash_cmds}
EOD;
```

results in `Array` being echoed in php (v5.3.3). Is there a special way to handle arrays inside a heredoc? I can't find any info on this, only the reciprocal appending heredocs to arrays.

This `$bash_script` will eventually be written to a file obviously, so perhaps there's a better solution to what I'm trying to do. My efforts to research this have been fruitless, though. Any input would help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with heredoc. You cannot concatenate an array to a string but need to use a function like [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) first

Comment: You would either need to explicitly state each command in the array `{$arr[0]}\n{$arr[1]}` or implode the array.

Comment: Thank you both. My mistake for overlooking something so simple.

Comment: For anyone's future reference, `implode(PHP_EOL, $my_array)` will properly implode the array with the appropriate end of line character for the bash script execution. `\n` or `\\n` do not appear to work.